# python-opening a shortcut file in write mode gives me a return value 41

Tags: python, file, shortcut

I was experimenting on files using python when I found out that opening a shortcut file in write mode returns 41, this is the code i used:

```
>>>with open('programs.lnk - Copy','w') as f:
       f.write("C:\\Users\\DEVDHRITI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs")

    
>>>41
```

is this a bug or some specific id??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not a bug. It's is part of the API. Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects),

> `f.write(string)` writes the contents of string to the file,
> ***returning the number of characters written.***

```
>>> f.write('This is a test\n')
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually try to open the file for writing here and not the target.
Link files is a windows specific feature. And to open the target you could do something like this:

```
import sys
import win32com.client 

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut("t:\\test.lnk")
print(shortcut.Targetpath)
```

Comment: actually ik how to get the shortcut's destination, i was just trying to read the code inside it to see if i could get something new